# Is it possible to define a group with a piecewise operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can one define a group with a piecewise operation, I.e. an operation that is different for different inputs of elements, as long as in totality, the operation satisfies the laws of defining a group (closure, associativity, identity)?

If so, are there any examples of such groups?

Comment: Yes, as long as the group conditions are satisfied, that's fine. Describing one is kinda hard.

Comment: A group table (for a finite group) defines the operation piecewise in the ultimate way, one pair at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a cyclic group of order $2$, $G=\langle x \rangle$ as example. I can define the operation on $G=\{1,x\}$ such that
(i) $a\star b=e$ if $a=b$
(ii) $a\star b=x$ if $a\neq b$.
Then $\star$ is a piecewise binary operation on $G$ where $(G,\star)$ is a group.

Answer (score 2):

If you view integer addition modulo $N$ as a group consisting of $\{0, 1, \ldots, N-1\}$, with the operation given by
$$a \oplus b = \begin{cases}a+b & \text{ if } a+b < N \\ a+b-N & \text{ otherwise, }\end{cases}$$
then associativity of $\oplus$ might look rather mysterious. It gets worse when you define the multiplicative group in the analogous way.